# Clear-Host not working when called from within a Class

Tags: powershell

#### Env:

Powershell Version: 6.2.3

MscOs: Catalina

#### Do you know why

`Clear-Host` does not work, when called from within a Class - like this:

```
# Clear-Host << This works?
Class Menu {
  ShowMenu(){Clear-Host} # Not working
}

$menu = [Menu]::New()
$menu.ShowMenu()
```

But in a function outside a class it does work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like **you've run into a bug in v6.2.3**, the most recent stable version as of this writing, which you can report [on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues): The external `/usr/bin/clear` utility that is ultimately invoked by the predefined `Clear-Host` function simply fails quietly when invoked from a custom-class method<sup>[1]</sup>.

The bug is no longer present in the most recent preview version of the upcoming v7.0 release, v7.0.0-rc2.

In the meantime, you can use the following **workaround**:

```
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 6) {
  # Redefine Clear-Host to use [Console]::Clear() instead of calling /usr/bin/clear
  # If you want to fix this globally, use `function global:Clear-Host ...`
  function Clear-Host { [Console]::Clear() }
}

Class Menu {
  ShowMenu(){Clear-Host}
}

$menu = [Menu]::New()
$menu.ShowMenu()
```

Note that the redefined `Clear-Host` is then *console*-specific (terminal-specific), whereas `*-Host` commands are generally expected to work with *all* types of PowerShell host applications.
However, even the predefined `Clear-Host` is console-specific as of v7.0.0-rc2 - see [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10181#issuecomment-537510875).

---

<sup>[1] The reason is that the output from `/usr/bin/clear` isn't passed through to the terminal, because output from external programs is *generally* not passed through, given that the only way to return (success) output from a method is via the `return` statement. 
As of v7.0.0-rc.2, this has been corrected by wrapping the `/usr/bin/clear` call in `[Console]::Write()`. Arguably, though, the workaround proposed above - calling `[Console]::Clear()` directly - is the simplest implementation in general.</sup>